# "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `pet_name` on serializer `PatientSerializer`

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

I am trying to get the most popular pet type with viewsets in django, but when i write this code

```
class PopularPetTypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Patient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PatientSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            return models.Patient.objects.values('pet_type').annotate(count=Count('pet_type')).order_by('-count')
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error':str(e)})
```

i get this error

> Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `pet_name` on serializer `PatientSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'pet_name'."

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# Create your models here.
class Patient(models.Model):

    pet_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cat = 'cat'
    dog = 'dog'
    bird = 'bird'
    PET_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (cat, cat),
        (dog, dog),
        (bird, bird),
    ]
    pet_type = models.CharField("Select Pet Type", choices=PET_TYPE_CHOICES, null=False, max_length=15)
    owner_name = models.CharField("Owner Name",max_length=255)
    owner_address = models.CharField("Owner Address", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    owner_phone_number = models.CharField("phone", max_length=11, blank=False, default='')
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    
    
class PatientAppointment(models.Model):
    patient_id = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True) #, null=TrueSS)
    appointment_start_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Appointment start time"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    appointment_end_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Appointment end time"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    description = models.CharField(_("Enter description"), max_length=1024)
    USD = 'USD'
    EUR = 'EUR'
    BITCOIN = 'BITCOIN'
    PAYMENT_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (USD, USD),
        (EUR, EUR),
        (BITCOIN, BITCOIN),
    ]
    payment_type = models.CharField("Select payment Type", choices=PAYMENT_TYPE_CHOICES, null=False, max_length=15, default='USD')
    paid_amount = models.DecimalField(_("Enter amount paid"), max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    unpaid_amount = models.DecimalField(_("Enter unpaid amount"), max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(_("Enter Total amount"), max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Patient, PatientAppointment
# from pets_hospital.settings import DATETIME_FORMAT

class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = (
            'id',
            'pet_name',
            'pet_type',
            'owner_address',
            'owner_name',
            'owner_phone_number')
    pet_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    pet_type = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    owner_address = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    owner_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    owner_phone_number = serializers.CharField(required=True, min_length=9,max_length=11)
    

class PatientAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PatientAppointment
        fields = (
            'id',
            'appointment_start_time',
            'appointment_end_time',
            'description',
            'payment_type',
            'unpaid_amount',
            'paid_amount',
            'total_amount',
            'patient_id',
            'appointments',
        )
    appointment_start_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)
    appointment_end_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    payment_type = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    paid_amount = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    unpaid_amount = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    total_amount = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    appointments = PatientSerializer(source='patient_id',read_only=True)
```

i did my research on this error and they all are asking to specify field_name(pet_name) in serializers but I have already mentioned it and getting same error.

Comment: Have you migrated your model changes? With `python manage.py makemigrations`  and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yes i did both py manage.py makemigrations and py manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you `get_queryset` method returns a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, rather than model instances (see [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values)). It is a `ModelViewSet`, so it needs to return `QuerySet` of model instances (like `models.Patient.objects.all()`).

Also having both `queryset` and `get_queryset()` defined is redundant, you need one or another only. Try removing `get_queryset()` and check if it works.

Comment: i have tried only one queryset but getting same error...what should i use instead of values()?